# Magento 2 Make products clickable in items ordered

Tags: magento2, orders

Is there any way to get the product name clickable and so that It leads to the specific product page?

I was looking at this before but there was no answers:
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Feature-Requests-and/Make-products-clickable-in-sales-order-view-direct-link-to/idi-p/136197

[image]

Comment: are you use custom theme ?????????

Comment: if you are simply after making the product name clickable edit Magento_Sales/templates/order/items/renderer/default.phtml you will need to load the product or possibly see if the getProduct function exists as part of the row data